# Update Trigger on Parent record on Roll-up summary field when child records are inserted or deleted?

Tags: trigger, roll-up-summary

I want to build an update trigger on a rollup summary field.

Say I have a parent record A,  A have 1000 children records linked with a Master-Detail relationship.

1.First Operation: delete 1000 records,  if the code is like

```
List<Child__c> children = [select id from Child__c where parentid = A.Id];
delete children;
```

How many times would the update trigger on parent record A run?

Is it 5?   What if the second 200 batch is being deleted when the first update trigger is running? I'm confused with the execution order and the events start&end order.

2.Second Operation: insert 1000 child records from data loader or any external app.

How many times would the update trigger on parent record A run?
Is it 5?  Is it similar to the delete operation?

Thanks

**Update**

The Roll up summary field is a "SUM" of it's children records field num__c which has a number type.

The question assumes the num__c field of the deleted&inserted children records have value on this field.

The question also specified 1000 child records belongs to a same parent record

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to specify the content of your `Rollup Summary` field? Are you performing a `COUNT` operation? `SUM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update triggers on parent will be fire .200 child records are processed at a time when you delete 1000 records .This means there will be 5 chunks .Lets say 200 child belongs to 10 parent records ,trigger.new will have 10 parent records .

The trigger on Parent would run for update case .In your case you are deleting or inserting and that should trigger update triggers on parent records .

To confirm this behavior just did a quick experiment

1.Create a parent object and a child object .Associate them via master detail .

2.Create a number field on the child record .

3.Create a roll up summary field on the parent record summing the number field that's created in previous field

4.Create a trigger on the parent record like below

```
trigger triggerSpeaker on Parent__c (before update) {
  if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isupdate){
    for(Parent__c sp:trigger.old ){
      sp.addError('You cannot update me');
    }
  }
 }
```

5.Delete or insert the data into child objects via data loader or developer console.You should see the add error indicating triggers fire

Comment: I see a negative vote .Could you please elaborate the reason why this answer is negatively voted ?

Comment: Hi just see your answer. Let's say the roll up summary is a sum of its children's field num__c and the question's assumption is the deleted&inserted children records have value on field num__c

Comment: Still the answer holds correct .please try in dev org before concluding it's wrong .triggers won't fire at all.

Comment: Ok I didn't down vote the answer

Comment: @sfdcnoob cool.please verify the response .sorry about me assuming you down voted this .

Comment: So based on the assumption the trigger should fire, right?  Can you read my questions again?

Comment: It will be 5 batches if triggers fire and records in context will be locked till execution. There is no parallel processing. Hope it's clear

Comment: Does this mean if I delete 1000 records the second batch would possibly fail?

Comment: No..when you delete 1000 records ..2nd chunk processing will happen once first chunk gets processed

Comment: It's serial .All 5 batches will go through .Hope that's clear

Comment: Your POC is flawed. The rollup wouldn't `delete` parent records, it would `update` them.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sorry when did i say rollup will delete parent record ? And its about whether trigger will fire ?

Comment: Trigger on parent wont fire when a child is deleted .I can confirm that .Let me know if you need more explanation or you see ways to improve this answer

Comment: If you are trying to prove the triggers on `Parent` do not fire, you should examine the `update` trigger. Why would rollup recalculation fire `delete` or `insert`? It doesn't make sense. I didn't downvote btw, I would have upvoted but you seem to be checking the wrong operation. At least if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: You're trying to figure out if `delete` on `Child` causes `update` on `Parent`. It certainly won't fire `insert` and is very unlikely to fire `delete`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ah i see your point .The question was to find update on the Parent .Yes then triggers will fire for sure .Thanks .Let me update my answer .